# 17.10 Scrolling buggy after switching workspace

Tags: mouse, 17.10, workspaces, scrolling, workspace-switcher

In about 1/3 of the times I switch workspaces in Ubuntu 17.10, the scroll on my mouse goes completely haywire first time I use it. It might go the wrong way, jump several 'ticks' of the scroll wheel, etc.

It happens with multiple mice, and it fixes itself after the first time. It also happens on pretty much any scrollable content (web pages, music playlists, documents, etc). Obviously, this can easily cause you to lose where you left off in your work and it's just straight up confusing.

Anybody encounter this? If so, did you manage to fix it?

If this question seems familiar to some of you, that's because it's a copy of the same question I posed last week for 17.04. I was informed that 17.04 was no longer supported so I upgraded in hopes of this issue being fixed. It was not :(

Comment: I'm having the same issue, when I scroll in an application and alternate to another looks like  the scrolling movement done at the previous window is applied again in the first scroll I do, so if I scroll up 5 lines in VSCode and alternate to Google Chrome I scroll 1 line down and it goes 4 lines up. This is a really nonsense behaviour. Did you got any solution to this?

Comment: Nope. I tried the fix I did for the same issue on 17.04 and it just does nothing.

Comment: I too suffer from this, its annoying. I'd love to know the solution to this.

Comment: I upgraded to 18.04 and while there are other issues, this one seems resolved. I don't think that's much of a solution, so this question will stay opened.